# How to use icons for firebase logging in?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

The following is my code for logging in using social media buttons with firebase

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // FirebaseUI config.
  var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: 'https://xx.html',
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
     // firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
     // firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
     // firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ]
  };

  // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
  var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
  ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
</script>
```

After this in the body I use `<div id="firebaseui-auth-container></div` This shows up a bunch of buttons which I do not want.

I have a template and they have icons for facebook, etc which I want to use. I want the icons to work like the buttons firebaseui-auth-container provides.

Here is the html for the buttons in the template

```
<div class="social-line">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-just-icon" id="firebaseui-auth-container">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
    </a>

    <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-simple btn-just-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>

    <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-simple btn-just-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

How do I do that?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From the github repo: Currently, FirebaseUI does not offer customization out of the box. However, the HTML around the widget is not affected by it so you can display everything you want around the widget container. https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/README.md#customizing-firebaseui-for-authentication

Comment: @Hackerman I didn't quite understand what you said. Would you kindly explain a little more? Is there any other option that unsing firebaseui-auth-container, where we can just click on the fb icon or google icon and the respective page opens up?

Comment: They do not support that kind of customization...you can do it in a hacky way, but if they change something your hacky code could not longer work.

Comment: @Hackerman ok.. Is there any other way? Where I do not use firebaseui-auth-container?

Comment: Let me build a sample

Comment: @Hackerman Ok ! :)

Comment: @Hackerman any update?

Comment: No luck man, I tried to setup a fiddle with no luck.